# Env vars and Docker differences between dev, staging, and prod

Tags: django, docker, testing, heroku, devops

Although my specific example involves Django, Docker, and Heroku, I believe these are pretty general testing/QA questions.

I have a dockerized Django app tested in dev with Selenium confirming that my static files are being served correctly from my local folder (`EXPECTED_ROOT = '/staticfiles/'`). This app is deployed to Heroku and I can see (visually and in the dev tools) that the static files are being pulled in from CloudFront correctly as well. I want to formalize this with the same test I'm using in dev. My first question is related to if/how environment variables are used for tests:

- Do I add for example `EXPECTED_ROOT = 'https://<somehash>.cloudfront.net/'` as an env var to Heroku and use it in the Selenium test?

Also, to run this test in staging I would need to install Firefox in my Docker image like I do in dev. Perhaps this is ok in staging, but in prod I believe I should be aiming for the the smallest image possible. So the question is about differences between staging and prod:

- Do I keep Firefox in my staging image, run the tests, and then send
  to production a replica of that Dockerfile, but now without firefox?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idea of `Config Var` is to setup configuration variables that differ from environment to environment. Having said that you are in control of the environment and can define what you need.

I personally would use a different approach: create a test that is independent of the environment (for example instead of testing the `expected root` I would confirm a given `DIV ID` is found, or some other element).
This would be enough to confirm the test is successful and the functionality works as expected.

The production Dockerfile indeed does not need Selenium and can be different from the one from staging.

Comment: The whole point of that test is to confirm that in dev static files are being served from one place while in prod they are served from another. It is inherently env specific. Testing for example that a certain div exists wouldn't really help here.

Comment: I see, again it depends on the goal of testing, in your case it is fine to define a Config Var with the setting you need (and ensuring each environment is properly configured)

Comment: I see, ok thanks. I'll consider your response the answer, since it addresses my first question. I probably should've created 2 different posts, one for each question so that's on me.